# Auto-Vectorization in Visual Studio 2012 express on std::vector is not happening

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, stdvector, sse2, auto-vectorization

I am having a simple program in which i am having 3 std::vector and using them in for loops. After enabling the compilation flag ON, i am testing whether these loops are optimized or not. But visual studio is showing that loop is not vectorized due to reason 1200. My sample code is as below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <time.h>
int main(char *argv[], int argc)
{
    clock_t t=clock();
    int tempSize=100;
    std::vector<double> tempVec(tempSize);
    std::vector<double> tempVec1(tempSize);
    std::vector<double> tempVec2(tempSize);

    for(int i=0;i<tempSize;i++)
    {
        tempVec1[i] = 20;
        tempVec2[i] = 30;
    }

    for(int i=0,imax=tempSize;i<imax;i++)
        tempVec[i] = tempVec1[i] + tempVec2[i];

    t =clock()-t;          // stop the clock
    std::cout <<"Time in millisecs = " <<  t/double(CLOCKS_PER_SEC) <<      std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

And below is the output of this code compilation using option "/Qvec-report:2" enabled.

*2>  --- Analyzing function: main
2>  d:\test\ssetestonvectors\main.cpp(12) : info C5002: loop not vectorized due to reason '1200'
2>  d:\test\ssetestonvectors\main.cpp(18) : info C5002: loop not vectorized due to reason '1200'*

When i read about the error code 1200 on msdn page:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj658585.aspx
It specifies that error code 1200 is due to "Loop contains loop carried data dependence"

I am unable to understand how this loop is containing that. I am having some sort of code that i need to optimize so that it can use Auto-Vectorization feature of Visual studio so that it can be optimized for SSE2. This code contains vector operations. So i am unable to do that because each time visual studio is showing some error code like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your problem is that:

```
    for(int i=0,imax=tempSize;i<imax;i++)
        tempVec[i] = tempVec1[i] + tempVec2[i];
```

Is *actually*

```
    for(int i=0,imax=tempSize;i<imax;i++)
        tempVec.operator[](i) = tempVec1.operator[](i) + tempVec2.operator[](i);
```

... and the vectorizer is failing to look insider the function calls.  The first fix for that is:

```
    const double* t1 = &tempVec1.front();
    const double* t2 = &tempVec2.front();
    double *t = &tempVec.front();
    for(int i=0,imax=tempSize;i<imax;i++)
        t[i] = t1[i] + t2[i];
```

The problem with that, is that the vectoriser can't see that t, t1, and t2 don't overlap.  You have to promise the compiler they don't:

```
    const double* __restrict t1 = &tempVec1.front();
    const double* __restrict t2 = &tempVec2.front();
    double * __restrict t = &tempVec.front();
    for(int i=0,imax=tempSize;i<imax;i++)
        t[i] = t1[i] + t2[i];
```

Obviously (I hope) use of the `__restrict` keyword (which is not part of standard C++) means this code will not be portable to other C++ compilers.

**Edit**: The OP has clarified that replacing calls to `operator[]` with call to `at` produces a different failure message (although that *might* be because `at` is more complex).

If the problem is not the function calls, my next hypothesis is that `operator []` boils down to something like `return this.__begin[i];` and the vectorizer doesn't know that different `std::vector`s have non-overlapping memory.  If so, the final code block is still the solution.

Comment: Thanks Martin for your suggestions, Actually as you have said in the very first

Comment: Sorry for half comment. It was done by mistake.
As you have added that vectorizer is failing to look into the function call, i doubt it a little bit because if i use `tempVec.at(i) = tempVec1.at(i) + tempVec2.at(i)` instead of `tempVec[i] = tempVec1[i] + tempVec2[i];` then compiler through the reason as 500 which comes due to function calls.
Your suggested code works for optimization. Can you please suggest any link from where i can learn actually to convert a code for auto vectorization.

Thanks again for the Answer.

Comment: Interesting.  Note that the documentation for 1200 says that a call to "fn()" will suppress vectorization.  Maybe the problem was just that std::vector has a non-restrict pointer internally, and the vectorizer didn't know it must be unique (so creating the restrict pointers is what fixes it)/

Comment: I have no idea how you convert code for auto-vectorization, apart from a) enable the warnings; b) read the warning messages; c) work out what they mean.  You *might* find that a new version of VS helps.

Comment: Oh! what a silly mistake of mine, i didn't notice that _fn()_ function calling. BTW thanks for your suggestion i'll also try a new version of VS.

Comment: `.at()` can throw an exception. That immediately means that the loop count is no longer fixed (at least, as far as the compiler can prove). This will break vectorization as the vectorized code cannot throw the exception at the right point.

Comment: Yes, this may be the reason for code 500. However i am again stuck at some point while using `std::vector<Eigen::vector3d>` When i am performing the operations on vectors of Eigen type then It's showing error type 1304 i.e. _Loop contains assignment that are of different sizes_. I've found a link: http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TopicStlContainers.html Which states that how to align Eigen::vectors but this didn't help either.I don't know how to tell the compiler that it's fixed size data.
    std::vector<Eigen::Vector3d,Eigen::aligned_allocator<Eigen::Vector3d>> eiVec(tempSize);

Comment: That's a different question.

Comment: Ok let me post it as a different question. I'll update the link here :)

Comment: I've post it as another question on the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40084969/auto-vectorization-in-visual-studio-2012-on-vectors-of-eigen-type-is-not-perform

Comment: GNU C++ (the set of extensions supported by gcc, clang, icc, and many other compilers) allows `__restrict__`, so you could use some `#ifdef`s to create a `#define` that gives you a working `restrict` for compilers you know about, or nothing for other compilers.

Comment: Yes Peter Cordes, I am using _cmake_ so i can provide _#ifdef_ for conditional compilation.

Answer (score 2):

Auto-vectorization is a rather new feature of MSVC, and you're using an older version of MSVC. So it's far from perfect. Microsoft knows that, so they've decided to only vectorize code when it is absolutely safe.

The particular error message is a bit terse. In reality, it should say "Loop *might* contain loop-carried data dependence". Since MSVC can't prove their absence, it doesn't vectorize.

Comment: Thanks MSalters to look into the problem. As i read about the autovectorization feature of visual studio, they have introduced it int visual studio 2012 and i am using the same. There is a series of blog post they have written about it (https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/nativeconcurrency/2012/04/12/auto-vectorizer-in-visual-studio-2012-overview/).

Comment: May be it would be less informative messages in older version of VS.